# Error : "The process cannot access the file '' because it is being used by another process" while writing the log information

Tags: c#-4.0

This is my code. Could you please anyone tell me the reason for the error which i mentioned. Using statement usually dispose the object once it went out of scope, but i am getting the error.

```
    public static void WriteLogFile(string message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(message);

        if (File.Exists("C:\\log.txt"))
        {
            using (StreamWriter SWriter = File.AppendText("C:\\log.txt"))
            {
                SWriter.WriteLine(message);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            using (StreamWriter SWriter = File.CreateText("C:\\log.txt"))
            {

                SWriter.WriteLine(message);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is your application multi-threaded? Do you have multiple threads calling this function?

Comment: No Joachim Pileborg. I am not performing any multi threading process in the code

Answer (score 0):

If this file is not used somewhere else in your code, you can try with the below code

```
    public static void WriteLogFile(string message)
    {
        StreamWriter writer = null;
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine(message);
            writer = new StreamWriter("C:\\log.txt", true);
            writer.Write(message);
            writer.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            if (writer != null)
            { writer.Dispose(); }
        }
    }
```

Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am not supposed to use Try Catch finally in my code. I need a solution using "Using" statement